# How to install USBIP in Docker Container

Tags: docker, kernel, usb, wsl-2

I want to use USBIP in an Ubuntu 20.04 Docker Container. I tried installing the "linux-tools-generic" Package, but when i run USBIP afterwards i get the message:

```
You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-standard-WSL2
```

How can i install these Packages ? Could'nt find them with apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Docker relies on the features of the Linux kernel, you'll need to make sure that you have the USB/IP module compiled into your WSL kernel.  It is not there in the stock WSL kernel, so you'll need to build your own.  I haven't done this with USB/IP myself, but there are reports from the Home Assistant (home automation) forums that indicate that it works.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69195486/11810933) for more details.

Comment: I thought i would get around this :D. But seems like there is no other option. I tried the custom kernel you linked but it sadly didnt have all necessary modules... guess i will have to compile my own. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @Marius Looking forward to hearing how it goes.

Comment: @Marius Just noticed that the latest [Microsoft WSL2 kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases) release has USB/IP support built-in.  Might be worth trying if you haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds where can I find more information to accomplish this? I'm struggling with follow the following official guide https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/ since I've not much experience with Linux, at least in that sense.

Comment: @JoséPulido I hadn't even seen that Microsoft blog entry yet.  I haven't tried USP/IP myself, but now that the official support is there, I'll try it when I get a chance.  You may want to create a new question (probably on [Super User](https://superuser.com) detailing what you've done so far and what doesn't seem to be working (or where you have questions about something in the guide).

Comment: Many thanks, I'll be waiting for your updates, meanwhile I'll also make a post on Super User.